# Mac Console Log Messages, reccuring issue

Tags: macos, mac, imac

My log file is littered with the following entries:

```
(com.qbix.CalendarStart): Exited with code: 1
(com.qbix.CalendarStart): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

As you can imagine, this happens every 10 seconds.  How do I make this go away?

UPDATE: just wanted to add that MMB noted the following: "It appears you've installed "Calendar for Mac" from qbix.com."

I have already uninstalled this app and removed any files associated with qbix from ~/Library

SOLUTION: launchctl remove com.qbix.CalendarStart

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've installed "Calendar for Mac" from qbix.com.  The simplest method to make this error go away is to uninstall the program.  Unfortunately, the support site listed via the App Store seems to be borderline abandoned.  I'd uninstall and flee...

Good luck,
-MB

Comment: I've already uninstalled it and removed any reference files in ~/Library